# Selector de ListView e ImageButton não funciona

Tags: android, android-layout

Tanto o botão quando a ListView não sofrem modificações quando clicados, mas as definições de quando o item não é pressionado funcionam.

**ListView**:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaListas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#FFECECEC"
        android:dividerHeight="2sp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/novalista"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_item_listview">
    </ListView>
```

**layout_item_listview:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/layout_item_selecionado" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/layout_item_normal" />
</selector>
```

**layout_item_selecionado:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/item_selecionado"/>
</shape>
```

**layout_item_normal:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/vermelho"/>
</shape>
```

**Botao:**

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@color/amarelo"
            android:src="@drawable/img_estrelabotao"
            android:id="@+id/btnfavorito"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            style="@style/estiloBotaoFavorito"/>
```

**estiloBotaoFavorito:**

```
<style name="estiloBotaoFavorito">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/layout_botao_favorito</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/icons</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
    </style>
```

**layout_botao_favorito:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/layout_botao_favorito_pressionado"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/layout_botao_favorito_normal"/>
</selector>
```

**layout_botao_favorito_pressionado:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:drawable="@drawable/nine_patch_retangulo"
        android:color="@color/amarelo_escuro"
        android:elevation="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

**layout_botao_favorito_normal:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:drawable="@drawable/nine_patch_retangulo"
        android:color="@color/amarelo"
        android:elevation="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

Outra dúvida que tenho é se dentro do shape do botão eu posso definir elevation e o drawable? Como não acusou erro eu deixei assim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ordem como são declarados os estados tem importância na forma como são aplicados, o que nem sempre é óbvio.

A melhor forma de evitar essas situações é declarar o menor número de estados possíveis e fazê-lo em itens separados.

Altere os selectores assim:

**layout_item_listview:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/layout_item_selecionado" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/layout_item_selecionado" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/layout_item_selecionado"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/layout_item_normal" />
</selector>
```

Para que a selecção fique activada é necessário acrescentar `android:state_activated="true"` e que seja declarado, na *ListView*, o atributo `android:choiceMode` com um modo diferente de `none`.

**Nota:** Este selector deve ser atribuído ao *background* do *layout* do item da lista e não ao da *ListView*.

**layout_botao_favorito:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/layout_botao_favorito_pressionado"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/layout_botao_favorito_normal"/>
</selector>
```

O último `<item>`, aquele que não tem estado definido, será aplicado por padrão(quando nenhum dos anteriores se verificar).

Em relação à outra dúvida, a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) apenas indica o atributo `android:color` a poder ser usado no elemento `<solid>`.

Comment: fiz o que você falou e coloquei o choiceMode como singleChoice e continuou não funcionando

Comment: Editei a resposta, faltava o estado `state_activated`. Tenha atenção à nota que adicionei.

Comment: Deu certo! Os Buttons não estavam funcionando pq além do style eu tinha definido um background. Tirei o background e funcionou direitinho! Obrigada :)

Comment: Eu estou com o mesmo problema, o meu codigo esta do jeito que vc falou ramaral, porem somente qdo clico no imagebutton ele faz algo, agora quando clico no item do listview ele não seleciona aparentemente ele nem clama a função onClick (se eu tiro o button funciona normalmente), o meu choiceMode é multipleChoice.

Comment: @JoãoCarlos sem ver o código fica difícil de saber a razão. Veja se está a fazer tudo o que é descrito na resposta. Se não resolver, abra um nova pergunta.

Comment: Eu fiz uma pergunta da uma olhadinha la pra mim.https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237218/ao-adicionar-imagebutton-selector-de-listview-para-de-funcionar?noredirect=1#comment485869_237218

Comment: Vi-a pouco depois de ter comentado. Não vejo nada de errado em relação ao problema que indica.