# Ao adicionar ImageButton Selector de ListView para de Funcionar

Tags: android, listview

O list view é uma lista de itens disponiveis para o usuario selecionar, e quando o usuario clica em um item do ListView este item muda de cor e é adicionado em um arraylist (esta é a função do clique em um item do ListView), ja a função do botão que ha em cada item do ListView é, se clicado vai pra outra tela pra mostrar a descrição completa do item, o problema é, sem este ImageButton no meu Layout do ListView, os items são selecionados corretamente mudando de cor e adicionando no arraylist, ao colocar o botão de informação no Layout do ListView, somente o botão funciona corretamente ou seja, ao clicar no Item do ListView nada acontece mas ao clicar no botão ele muda de tela corretamente.Segue uma imagem da tela do app, neste caso o FloattingActionButton esta funcionando corretamente o problema é com os items do list view.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**item_lista_supermercado.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/selected_item"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageItem"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="50px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preco"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_info" />

</RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_supermercado.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.joao.mercado.SupermercadoActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnConcluido"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/vermelho"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/checked_black"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstProdutos"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**SupermercadoActivity.java**

```
package com.example.joao.mercado;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SupermercadoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listaProdutos;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adpDados;
private FloatingActionButton btnConcluido;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_supermercado);

    final ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        Item item = new Item(i,  10.01f, "Item num; " + i);
        items.add(item);
    }
    final ArrayList<Item> itemsSelecionados = new ArrayList<Item>();
    listaProdutos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstProdutos);
    listaProdutos.setAdapter(new SupermercadoItemAdapter(this, items));
    listaProdutos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                                int posicao, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!itemsSelecionados.contains(items.get(posicao))) {
                itemsSelecionados.add(items.get(posicao));
            }else{
                itemsSelecionados.remove(items.get(posicao));
            }
            Toast.makeText(SupermercadoActivity.this, "clicado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btnConcluido = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btnConcluido);

    btnConcluido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent it = new Intent(SupermercadoActivity.this, Carrinho.class);
            it.putParcelableArrayListExtra("itemsSelecionados", itemsSelecionados);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });

}
}
```

**selected_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/background_light"/>
</selector>
```

**supermercado_item_adapter**

```
package com.example.joao.mercado;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by Joao on 25/08/2017.
 */

public class SupermercadoItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Item> lista;


public SupermercadoItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> lista) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lista = lista;
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return lista.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Item item = lista.get(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista_supermercado, null);
    TextView preco = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.preco);
    TextView nome = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.nome);

    nome.setText(item.getNome());
    preco.setText("R$: "+item.getPreco());

    return layout;
}



}
```

Comment: Você está clicando exatamente em cima do `ImageButton`? Se sim, se clicar em qualquer outra parte do layout, funciona?

Comment: Como assim para de funcionar ? Porfavor, seje mais especifico... Da algum tipo de erro ? Se sim, qual ?

Comment: Quando eu clico no imagebutton ele chama a função on click, porem se eu clico no item do listView nada acontece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei a solução: Quando adicionado um ImageButton ao ListView ele "rouba" o foco do item do ListView para si mesmo. Para resolver isto basta adicionar a seguinte linha no root layout da sua ListView:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

No meu problema fica assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/selected_item"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:weightSum="1">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageItem"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="50px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/preco"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_info" />

</RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: O click na ImageButton continua a funcionar?

Comment: Ate onde eu testei nas funções do meu aplicativo sim.

Answer (score 0):

Ola,
pelo que eu entendi, você está tentando iniciar uma Activity ao clicar em um item da listview.
Em vez de usar:

> 

```
btnConcluido = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btnConcluido);

    btnConcluido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent it = new Intent(SupermercadoActivity.this, Carrinho.class);
            it.putParcelableArrayListExtra("itemsSelecionados", itemsSelecionados);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
```

Tente usar em sua ( `listaProdutos.setOnItemClickListener` )

```
 Intent it = new Intent(SupermercadoActivity.this, Carrinho.class);
        it.putParcelableArrayListExtra("itemsSelecionados", itemsSelecionados);
        startActivity(it);
```

Deixando assim:

```
    listaProdutos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstProdutos);
    listaProdutos.setAdapter(new SupermercadoItemAdapter(this, items));
    listaProdutos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                                int posicao, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!itemsSelecionados.contains(items.get(posicao))) {
                itemsSelecionados.add(items.get(posicao));
            }else{
                itemsSelecionados.remove(items.get(posicao));
            }
 Intent it = new Intent(SupermercadoActivity.this, Carrinho.class);
            it.putParcelableArrayListExtra("itemsSelecionados", itemsSelecionados);
            startActivity(it);
            Toast.makeText(SupermercadoActivity.this, "clicado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Esse não é o problema no entanto que quando um item do listview é clicado ele nem chama a função so SetOnClickListener.